# What happens to incoming email when an SMTP server is present but no IMAP/POP3 or backend store is present?

Tags: email, smtp, imap, pop3

Lets say i install an smtp server but no backend store where emails can be stored. I do not install any imap/pop3 server either.

What would happen to received email?

EDIT : I am talking about emails for virtual users and not local operating system users

Answer (score 1):

Unix/Linux system by default store incoming messages to local email domains in per OS account mailbox-files usually `/var/mail/username`.  Some command line tools (e.g. mail) allow access to "system mailbox (file)"

Comment: I mean Actually i mean only for virtual users(not system users)

Comment: It is much less "standardized".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what the question means...

In a mail/interop context the answer to this is: This is a local matter. A mail (IMAP/SMTP) server has to store mail somewhere when it's received, and it has to read it somewhere when it's accessed (IMAP/POP/JSONthings), but how it's stored is deliberately not specifed. The standards cover how you talk to the servers via the internet. How they talk to their disk is not. Put differently, internet matters are standardised, local matters are left completely up to the software used.